# Database name on Wordpress can't include hyphen, but our host has mandatory prefix-hyphen-name format

Tags: wordpress, database, installation

Is there any way we can work around this?

Our Joomla install was quite happy to use a db of format xxnn-yyyyyy.

When we create or rename db using phpMyAdmin we can only choose the yyyyyy. "xxnn-" is automatic.

The CiviCRM Installer had an error to the question
"Is the provided database name valid?   The database name provided is not valid. Please use only 0-9, a-z, A-Z and _ as characters in the name."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found how to resolve this one, but bit concerned that this fudge might break something further on down the line.

The CiviCRM installer page is driven by the file: `wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/install/index.php`.

This runs various checks and the db name check is on line 464 showing a call to CRM_Core_DAO to function requireValidDBName.

This function is in php file: `wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Core/DAO.php`.  Editing the `preg_match` string to include hyphens after the underscore allows these in the file name.

```
public static function requireValidDBName($database) {
  $matches = array();
  preg_match(
    "/^[0-9]*[a-zA-Z_-]+[a-zA-Z0-9_-]*$/",
    $database,
    $matches
  );
  if (empty($matches)) {
    return FALSE;
  }
  return TRUE;
}
```